# Merge multiple columns in Google Sheets from questions in Google Forms if all questions are the same

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form where I ask for the specific college someone is studying in (i.e. college of engineering, college of business, etc.) and then send them to a specific question where they select an option from a multiple choice of majors specific to their college.

This form sends responses to a Google Sheets file, which has multiple columns all named "major", but only one is even full because the users only answer the major question specific to their college. I don't want to just have one question where I ask their major because then there would be over a hundred they'd have to sort through. Is there a way to automatically merge these columns into one still named "major"?

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 0):

Choose **Insert > Sheet** and dynamically copy the data from the 'Form Responses 1' sheet there, using [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) to copy columns that do not require manipulation, and an array formula to copy the `major` column, like this:

`={ 'Form Responses 1'!A1:F }`

`=arrayformula( 'Form Responses 1'!G1:G & 'Form Responses 1'!M1:M & 'Form Responses 1'!P1:P )`

...where the responses to the `major` question appear in columns `G`, `M` and `P`.